# visual studio code auto add space to special characters?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using some extensions like Monokai Pro, Prettier, Quokka, Tabnine AI, TODO highlight ... and here is my problem

I want to code a very simple code, like this

```
rest1.numGuests ??= 10;
```

and my VS code auto make this tobe like this one

```
rest1.numGuests ? ? = 10;
```

it makes my code to be errors.

I am searching how to fix this one but still do now know how to fix, could you please give me some advices ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: look at your Code formatter that is called when you save the file, `Auto Format on Save` setting

Comment: Which node version are you using, must be v15+ for `??=` operator support.

Comment: @rioV8 you are right, I enable "Editor : Format on Save", should I unable it ?

Comment: it is a personal preference, I never used document formatting, it always destroys my layout